# Where can I find the URL of my AWS EC2 scaling group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, scaling, autoscaling, aws-auto-scaling

I've created an **auto-scaling group** based on an **EC2 launch template**, with an **internal load balancer**. I'm using **CodeDeploy** to deploy my application on the EC2 instances.

So far so good.

However, I don't find any URL for my scaling group. If I target the specific URL of an EC2 instance, it works fine, but that's not the point of a scaling group. I'd want to target a "group URL", with the internal load balancer redirecting the traffic to my instances.

Is my comprehension of a scaling group bad ? If not, where can I find such URL?

I'd even imagine that the instances should not be directly accessible from the web - only the load balancer should be able to communicate with them. But I guess that's another topic.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't find any URL for my scaling group

You can't find it, because there is no such thing. You must use **URL of your internal load balancer**. If you set up everything correctly, once you access the url of the internal balancer (from within VPC), then your requests should be redirected to the instances.

Comment: Hey @Marcin! You again! Thank you for your time :)

I don't quite get you though: if it's an internal load balancer, it means that it does not interface with public requests no? The only DNS I can find on the load balancer is something like 'internal-**" - and I can not query it from my browser.

Comment: @GaelF Because its internal load balancer. If you want balancer accessible from the internet, you should use  internet-facing, not internal.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Marcin, it was indeed the wrong type of lb!

Answer (score 0):

As @Marcin suggested you can have access to your group through load balancer. I know @GaeIF realized he was using the wrong type of load balancer but in case somebody is looking for the same information for the right kind of load balancer and you use AWS CLI:

```
aws elbv2 describe-load-balancers
```

This command is provided by the AWS CLI that retrieves information about Elastic Load Balancers (ELBs) from Amazon Web Services (AWS) using the Elastic Load Balancing V2 API.

When executed, the command makes a call to the AWS API endpoint for the Elastic Load Balancing V2 service, passing the necessary parameters to retrieve information about one or more load balancers. The command returns a JSON-formatted output that contains detailed information about the specified load balancers, such as the load balancer's ARN, DNS name, availability zones, listeners, security groups, target groups, and other attributes.

Some of the parameters that can be passed to this command include `--load-balancer-arn`s, `--names`, `--marker`, `--page-size`, and others, which can be used to filter and limit the results returned by the command.